# Unable to sign in to AAD OAuth Registered app

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, ssl-certificate, libcurl, azure-app-registration

We have integrated the OAuth app with AAD and provided the Client secret values along with other required values (APP ID, AAD Endpoints). However, app team getting an error message when they try to change the authentication method to Azure AD.  It appears that REDCap doesn’t like the Metadata link given, below is the error message that they are receiving.

Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/.well-known/openid-configuration?appid=0a1ce272-2520-4e6e-9e13-de1198936101 in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\redcap\redcap_v13.1.34\Libraries\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php:211 Stack trace: #0

Need your help in resolving this error.